# R delete last row in dataframe for each group

Tags: r

I would like to delete the last row in a dataframe for each group in R based on max(start_date).

Example data:

```
id      start_date  end_date
1       2016-01-14  2016-02-14
1       2016-03-14  2016-08-05
2       2014-01-14  2014-02-14
2       2015-03-21  2015-05-21
2       2015-08-23  2015-09-23
2       2015-11-21  2016-01-03
```

Result:

```
id      start_date  end_date
1       2016-01-14  2016-02-14
2       2014-01-14  2014-02-14
2       2015-03-21  2015-05-21
2       2015-08-23  2015-09-23
```

The following does not work:

```
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(start_date != max(start_date))
```

Error: found duplicated column name: id

```
df <- sqldf("select * from df group by id having start_date != max(start_date)")
```

error in statement: duplicate column name: id

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: use `filter()` instead of `summarise()`

Comment: In SQL use a correlated query: `sqldf("select * from df a where start_date not in  (select max(start_date) from df b where b.id = a.id)")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `slice` (assuming that the dates are already ordered)

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   slice(-n())
#     id start_date   end_date
#   <int>      <chr>      <chr>
#1     1 2016-01-14 2016-02-14
#2     2 2014-01-14 2014-02-14
#3     2 2015-03-21 2015-05-21
#4     2 2015-08-23 2015-09-23
```

If the dates are not ordered, then `arrange` and `slice`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(start_date) %>%
   slice(-n())
```

Based on some previous benchmarks (couldn't find the link), the `arrange/slice` method would be faster than comparing `start_date != max(start_date)`

Comment: `df1[, head(.SD, -1), by = .(id)]` alternatively