# Deleting every last row in every group in R

Tags: r

I need to delete every last row in a group after applying group_by.
I have tried something like that, but it does not work.

```
data=data %>%
  group_by(isin) %>%
   summarise(data=data[-length(isin),])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the the base function by

```
 new_data=do.call(rbind,by(data,data[,'isin'],function(x) x[-length(x),]))
```

By will return the groups in as list and do.call(rbind,...) will convert the list to a data.frame

Answer (score 2):

We use the built in `iris` data set as an example.  It has three groups of 50 rows each defined by the `Species` column.  Next time please provide sample data in the question.  See the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page for info.

**1) group_modify** We can use `group_modify` from dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_modify(~ head(., -1)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) slice** Another dplyr solution is to use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  slice(-n()) %>%
  ungroup
```

**3) by** A base solution is to use `by`.  It produces a list of data frames which we `rbind` back together.

```
do.call("rbind", by(iris, iris$Species, head, -1))
```

**4) subset/ave**  Another base solution is to create a vector of numbers which count down to 1 for each group and then only keep those rows corresponding to a number greater than 1.

```
subset(iris, ave(1:nrow(iris), Species, FUN = function(x) length(x):1) > 1)
```

**4a)** or keep all rows except the one having the maximum row number in each group:

```
n <- nrow(iris)
subset(iris, ave(1:n, Species, FUN = max) != 1:n)
```

**5) duplicated** Yet another base solution uses `duplicated`.  It only keeps rows whose Species column is duplicated counting back from the end.

```
subset(iris, duplicated(Species, fromLast = TRUE))
```

Comment: may be worth to add this nearly canonical answer to the duplicate thread :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916660/r-delete-last-row-in-dataframe-for-each-group